# Получение значение поля MySQLi

Tags: mysqli, mysql

```
echo mysql_result("mysql_query("select `name` from `users` where `id`=1"),0); и
echo mysql_result(musql_query("select count(*) from `users`"),0);
```

Как переписать данные кода под MySQLi?

```
$db->query("select count(*) from `users`")->num_rows;
```

Не работает.

Comment: @fujiop, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: кто знает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 код исправить ошибку синтаксиса

```
echo mysql_result(musql_query("select count(*) from `users`"),0);
echo mysql_result(mysql_query("select count(*) from `users`"),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("select count(*) from `users`")
```

Comment: а 2-й код?